# Caching/memoization vs object lifetime

Tags: rust

My program is structured as a series of function calls building up the resulting value - each function returns (moves) the returned value to it's caller. This is a simplified version:

```
struct Value {}

struct ValueBuilder {}

impl ValueBuilder {

    pub fn do_things_with_value(&mut self, v : &Value) {
        // expensive computations
    }

    pub fn make_value(&self) -> Value {
        Value {}
    }

    pub fn f(&mut self) -> Value {
        let v = self.make_value();
        self.do_things_with_value(&v);
        v
    }

    pub fn g(&mut self) -> Value {
        let v = self.f();
        self.do_things_with_value(&v);
        v
    }
}
```

[play.rust-lang version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1cd128fbeb4a691424de9feda87f22a8)

Imagine that there are many more functions similar to f and g, both between them and above. You can see that `do_things_with_value` is called twice with the same value. I would like to cache/memoize this call so that in the example below "expensive computations" are performed only once. This is my (obviously incorrect) attempt:

```
#[derive(PartialEq)]
struct Value {}

struct ValueBuilder<'a> {
    seen_values: Vec<&'a Value>,
}

impl<'a> ValueBuilder<'a> {
    pub fn do_things_with_value(&mut self, v: &'a Value) {
        if self.seen_values.iter().any(|x| **x == *v) {
            return;
        }
        self.seen_values.push(v)
        // expensive computations
    }

    pub fn make_value(&self) -> Value {
        Value {}
    }

    pub fn f(&mut self) -> Value {
        let v = self.make_value();
        self.do_things_with_value(&v); // error: `v` does not live long enough
        v
    }

    pub fn g(&mut self) -> Value {
        let v = self.f();
        self.do_things_with_value(&v);
        v
    }
}
```

[play.rust-lang version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=682497802f301806a3a78f7e038c3c9d)

I understand why the compiler is doing it - while in this case it happens that v is not dropped between two calls to `do_things_with_value`, there is no guarantee that it will not be dropped, and dereferencing it would crash the program.

What is a better way to structure this program? Let's assume that:

- cloning and storing `Values` is expensive, and we can't afford `seen_values` keeping a copy of everything we've ever seen
- we also can't refactor the code / `Value` object to carry additional data (i.e. a bool indicating whether we did expensive computations with this value). It needs to rely on comparing the values using `PartialEq`

Comment: Given your constraints, and without more details, I can only think of two options. Option one is to store Values directly in the cache and only give out references (maybe involving some cell type, etc.). This won't be suitable if you're sure you need to return Value directly. The other option is to store a hash of all seen Values, and simply hope that you don't get any collisions. If you need the value calculations to be absolutely correct, this isn't ideal.

Comment: How many values do you intend to store? A linear search through the vector is going to be expensive, it seems to me you should have some kind of `Set` or `Map`.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to keep the same value at different points in the program it's easiest to copy or clone it.

However, if cloning is not an option because it is too expensive wrap the values in an [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html). That is a reference counted smart pointer which allows shared ownership of its content. It is relatively cheap to clone without duplicating the contained value.

Note that simply storing `Rc<Value>` in `seen_values` will keep all values alive at least as long as the value builder lives. You can avoid that by storing [`Weak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Weak.html) references.

```
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

#[derive(PartialEq)]
struct Value {}

struct ValueBuilder {
    seen_values: Vec<Weak<Value>>,
}

impl ValueBuilder {
    pub fn do_things_with_value(&mut self, v: &Rc<Value>) {
        if self
            .seen_values
            .iter()
            .any(|x| x.upgrade().as_ref() == Some(v))
        {
            return;
        }
        self.seen_values.push(Rc::downgrade(v))
        // expensive computations
    }

    pub fn make_value(&self) -> Rc<Value> {
        Rc::new(Value {})
    }

    pub fn f(&mut self) -> Rc<Value> {
        let v = self.make_value();
        self.do_things_with_value(&v);
        v
    }

    pub fn g(&mut self) -> Rc<Value> {
        let v = self.f();
        self.do_things_with_value(&v);
        v
    }
}
```

While a `Rc<Value>` is in use by the chain of functions `do_things()` will remember the value and skip computations. If a value becomes unused (all references dropped) and is later created again, `do_things()` will repeat the computations.